# How can i return the SUM (summary) in this SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to get out the SUM directly from the sql query by random, but how can i return the sum of duration field from this query:
that's the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video_clips` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(155) NOT NULL,
      `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `rank` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

    INSERT INTO `video_clips` (`id`, `name`, `duration`, `rank`) VALUES
    (1, 'clip1', 3, 1),
    (2, 'clip2', 5, '3'),
    (3, 'clip3', 8, '2'),
    (4, 'clip4', 6, '1');
```

And That's the code:

```
$time=16;
while($sum=$time) {
$result=mysql_query("(SELECT duration FROM table where rank=1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) UNION ALL
(SELECT duration FROM table where rank=2 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) UNION ALL
(SELECT duration FROM table where rank=3 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1)" );

$sum=??????
}
```

or is that possible to add the result to an alias table and then return the SUM from this alias table something like that:

```
$time=16;
    while($sum=$time) {
    $result=mysql_query("(SELECT duration FROM table where rank=1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) UNION ALL
    (SELECT duration FROM table where rank=2 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) UNION ALL
    (SELECT duration FROM table where rank=3 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) AS table1");

    $sum=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(duration) FROM table1");
    }
```

IS that possible? i have tried but it's not working.

Comment: GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP

Answer (score 2):

Like @Dagon hinted in the comment, something like this:

```
SELECT rank, SUM(duration) 
FROM   video_clips
GROUP BY rank WITH ROLLUP
```

This will give you this result:

```
+------+---------------+
| rank | SUM(duration) |
+------+---------------+
|    1 |             9 |
|    2 |             8 |
|    3 |             5 |
| NULL |            22 |
+------+---------------+
```

The NULL for the grouped by column (rank) indicates that that row is a is a "super total".
More complex groupings are possible, for more info see:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: Thanks, It looks like it works for me but how can i add this condition (WHERE rank=2 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) because somrtimes i need more than one data in rank 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: Please be more specific. What is it that you want to do at random? Select some particular rank at random? Do you have need for the subtotal generated by the ROLLUP clause?

Comment: It's an app that the user want's let's say 16 minutes in 3 video clips and the vieo clips ranked by 1, 2, 3 or some times he want more than 16 minutes and want's to be the ranked 1 video clips to be more than 1 or 2 or 3 or more and any other ranks. first i wanted to make a program work row by row until it finds the video clips and it was looked like impossible so i tried to be random whech i thout it's better, that's my situation and im stuck in it for two weeks. so please help

Comment: @Aram: sorry, I still don't understand what you want. Can you phrase the use case with concrete data examples from the data set you posted in the original question?

Comment: ehm, no. Don't have time for that. Please spend some time to explain what you want.

Comment: Ok, I have a big database that contains video_clips, The video_clips ranked by it's qualitys from one to three and has duration's, And i have a web interface,in this interface i have 4 text inputs first one for howmany minutes i want second one for howmany ranked one video_clips i want and third one for howmany ranke two video_clips i want and fourd one for howmany ranked three video_clips i want, let's say i want 25 minutes devided by 2 video_clips ranked by 1 and 2 video_clips ranked by 2 and 1 video clips ranked by 3

Comment: @Aram, The problem is that you want to search a particular total. You'd have to make all possible combinations of video's eligible by rank before you can total their durations. This is not the kind of query you can efficiently do in a large RDBMS. What you could try is to calculate the average target duration in advance (duration / total number of rank 1,2,3 clips) and work that into the query. In the best case this will lead to a mix of clips that have about the same duration, in the worst case, you may not find a particular clip of desired rank and duration. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Thanks @Roland, That's exactly what i want with a little different that when i want 25 minutes it's not exactly the minutes i want it's ok to return 23 or 24 or 25 or 26 or 27.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this work?

```
SELECT (SELECT duration FROM table where rank=1 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) 
    + (SELECT duration FROM table where rank=2 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) 
    + (SELECT duration FROM table where rank=3 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) 
    AS sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aram, The problem is that you want to search a particular total. But before you can do that, you would have to make all possible combinations of video's eligible by rank before you can total their durations.

This is not the kind of query you can efficiently do in a large RDBMS.

What you could do is calculate the average duration of a clip in advance (desired duration / #number of clips) and use to create an extra condition to the query to find only clips within a particular duration range. But this is not enough: my assumption is that you also need to avoid selecting the same clip more than once.

While it may be possible to do this in a single query, my suggestion would now be to solve this procedurally in PHP code.

```
//find the min and max id of clips to set up efficient random row selection:
$sql = 'SELECT min(id) min_id, max(id) max_id FROM video_clips';
$res = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
$min_max = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$min = $min_max['min_id'];
$max = $min_max['max_id'];

//vars to hold the user preferences
$target_dur = $_GET['desired_duration'];
$count_clips_per_rank = array(
    1 => intval($_GET['count_rank1_clips'])
,   2 => intval($_GET['count_rank2_clips'])    
,   3 => intval($_GET['count_rank3_clips'])    
);
$total_count = array_sum($count_clips_per_rank); 

//vars to keep track of the clip selection so far.
$actual_dur = 0;
$actual_count = 0;    
$selection = array();
$selected_ids = '';

//query backbone
$base_sql = 'SELECT id, duration FROM video_clips WHERE rank = ';

//visit all desired ranks 
for ($rank = 1; $rank <= 3; $rank++) {

    //add a rank condition to find only clips of the desired rank
    $sql = $base_sql.$rank;

    //find the desired number of clips for this rank
    $n = $count_clips_per_rank[$rank];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {

        //establish a duration range (taking into account the selection so far)
        //we arbitrarily choose a range of +/- 5%
        $avg_dur = ($target_dur - $actual_dur) / ($total_count - $actual_count);
        $range = $avg_dur * 0.05;

        //add a condition to find only clips within the desired range
        $sql .= ' AND duration BETWEEN '
              . ($avg_dur - $range)
              . ' AND '  
              . ($avg_dur + $range)
        ;

        //add a condition to the query to exclude clips we found so far.
        if ($selected_ids !== '') {
            $sql .= $selected_ids.')'
        }

        //add a condition to the query to select a random clip
        $rand = rand($min_id, $max_id);
        $sql .= ' AND id > '.$rand.' LIMIT 1';

        //find a clip
        $res = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
        $clip = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
        if ($clip === FALSE) {
            //oops, no match found.
            ...intelligent code to deal with this error goes here...
        }

        //from here on, we assume we actually found a clip

        //update the selection with the newly found clip
        array_push($selection, $clip);

        //do bookkeeping for the next iterations.
        if ($selected_ids == '') {
            $selected_ids = ' AND id NOT IN (';
        }
        else {
            $selected_ids .= ',';
        }
        $selected_ids .= $clip['id'];
        $actual_dur .= $clip['duration'];
        $actual_count++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do something with this